# Как разделить recyclerView на два?

Tags: android

Я хочу сделать два RecyclerView, для утра и вечера.
В onCreate я использую две функции

```
       prepareRecyclerView("Утро");
       prepareRecyclerView("Вечер");
       
       prepareWordsList("Утро");
       prepareWordsList("Вечер");
```

Первая - это подключение адаптера и тд

```
private void prepareRecyclerView(String Period) {
       switch (Period) {
           case "Утро":
               mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMainMorning);
               break;
           case "Вечер":
               mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMainNight);
               break;
       }
       wordsList = new ArrayList<Word>();
       mRecyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), wordsList);
       mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       mRecyclerAdapter.setListener(this);
       mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
       mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
   }
```

Вторая-получение данных из БД

```
 private void prepareWordsList(String Period) {
       databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper3(this);
       // открываем подключение
       db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
       //УТРО
       //получаем данные из бд в виде курсора
       CursorPeriod = db.rawQuery("" +
               "select c.name, c.description " +
               "from type t " +
               "join main m on t._id=m.type_of_skin " +
               "join cosm c on m.id_cosm=c._id " +
               "where m.type_of_skin = (select _id from type where type = ?) and m.when_= ? ", new String[]{SkinType, Period});
       CountPeriodProduct = CursorPeriod.getCount();
       CursorPeriod.moveToFirst();
       //MorningProducts = new ArrayList<>();
       for (int i = 0; i < CountPeriodProduct; i++) {
           Word mapperClass = new Word(CursorPeriod.getString(0), CursorPeriod.getString(1));
           //wordsList.add( CursorMorning.getString(0));
           wordsList.add(mapperClass);
           CursorPeriod.moveToNext();
       }
   }
```

Но в итоге эти два RecyclerView "склеиваются" и выглядят как один. Я только начинаю изучать Андроид, подскажите, как решить эту проблему. И, возможно, в моем коде есть ещё какие-то ошибки, буду благодарна за указания на них.  Заранее спасибо!

**UPD**

Вот так это выглядит в редакторе, между ними есть ТекстВью

[image: Вот так это выглядит в редакторе, между ними есть ТекстВью]

[image: А вот так это выглядит в реальности, под склеиванием я подразумевала, что списки объединяются (то есть сейчас в том, что внизу информация по обоим запросам из БД]

А вот так это выглядит в реальности, под склеиванием я подразумевала, что списки объединяются (то есть сейчас в том, что внизу информация по обоим запросам из БД

Comment: Что значит разделить и что значит склеиваются? Ну поставьте между ними View-ху какую-то типа разделителя. Или скройте один из Recycler-ов. Что именно вам необходимо?

Comment: Добавила скрины в вопрос, между ними Текст вью, они привязаны каждый к своему заголовку, но все равно не получается....

Comment: `mRecyclerAdapter` - у Вас общая переменная, сделайте его локальной переменной внутри функции, либо сделайте две переменные для двух адаптеров. *Уточнение: Вы, вероятно, в БД обращаетесь асинхронно и потом добавляете данные только в последний созданный адаптер, так что надо получить две переменных для двух адаптеров

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Спасибо! Это сработало! Я объявила две глобальных переменных для адаптера, а в функции использовала `switch (Period)`  продублировав код, но с разными переменными. Можно ли это назвать правильным или есть более оптимальный вариант?

Comment: Странное решение... Может лучше использовать 1 адаптер и 1 `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev А как разделить на утро и вечер?

Comment: И, если можно, еще один вопрос. Я бы хотела считать дни подряд, когда выбраны все пункты в обоих RecyclerView. Можно ли как то это проверить средствами RecyclerView (все ли выбраны или хотя-бы сколько)?